# Is it possible to access native cell-phone or device APIs using Blazor to access camera, contacts etc?

Tags: asp.net, blazor

As Blazor let us build code for client side development, I was wondering whether there is any possibility to access native device APIs for cameras, contacts, etc.?

I have looked into a few documentation including this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0

However, I could not find any answer

Answer (score 4):

There no standard libraries shipped by MS, but there a lot of community libraries which wrap access to JS API in the browser:

Large list compiled here: https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor#libraries--extensions

- Geolocation: https://github.com/AspNetMonsters/Blazor.Geolocation
- Sensors: https://github.com/AspNetMonsters/Blazor.Sensors
- Speech Synthesis API: https://github.com/jsakamoto/Toolbelt.Blazor.SpeechSynthesis
- Storage: https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage
- Notifications API: https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Notifications
- Canvas: https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Canvas

This is not all list of extensions created by community, so free to look at the existing options.